# Laravel 5 viaRemember() always false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've read the laravel 5 documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication to see how i can implement a way to keep users logged in.

But somehow with the code below my function **Auth::viaRemember()** always returns false. 
Also after browser restart. However in my database **remember_token** is set and so is my **cookie**.

I'm a bit confused right now, can someone explain what probably is happening?

***This function is called to login the user***

```
public function doLogin()
{
        // create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true)) {

                return Redirect::to('aview');
                // validation successful!
        }
}
```

***This function is called to check logged in user by Auth::viaRemember()***

```
public function checkLogin()
{

    if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
        return Redirect::to('aview');
    } else {
        return view('toaview');
    }

}
```

***Additional routes file (just in case)***

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('login', 'UserController@checkLogin');
});
```

Comment: Auth::check() seems to work as an alternative can't 100% confirm this yet. Still need some testing.

Comment: You might find [this Github convo](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3318) a worthwhile read. I've had issues with `viaRemember()` myself on `5.2` but ultimately it came down to it returning false because I was being logged in via browser cache and not the `remember_me` token cookie set when the user checks to `remember_me`.